# Core data objects in different tableView sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a tableView with expandable/collapsable sections and fixed section titles, which I want to maintain. 
This is the code to do that:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 6;
}


+ (NSString*) titleForHeaderForSection:(int) section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0 : return @"Overdue";
        case 1 : return @"Today";
        case 2 : return @"Tomorrow";
        case 3 : return @"Upcoming";
        case 4 : return @"Someday";
        case 5 : return @"Completed";
       // default : return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section no. %i",section + 1];
    }
}
```

For the moment, I am populating the rows with following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 2 : return 1;
        case 3 : return 30;
        default : return 8;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0 : cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell"; break;
        case 1 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Second Cell"; break;
        case 2 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Third Cell"; break;
        case 3 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fourth Cell"; break;
        case 4 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fifth Cell"; break;
        case 5 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Sixth Cell"; break;
        case 6 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Seventh Cell"; break;
        case 7 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Eighth Cell"; break;
        default : cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.row + 1];
    }

    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = ...;

    return cell;
}
```

But I want to populate the rows from a core data entity, this is my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"tdText" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Core data entity is 'ToDoItem', and what I finally want is that each object appears inside the right section on the tableView. I need your help and advice.

---

To make my question a little bit clearer, I would create an attribute called tdDate, and this attribute should be the filtering key to decide under which section should the object be shown. Taking into account that an object with the current date will appear under the TODAY section today, tomorrow it should appear under the OVERDUE section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to achieve is to add a new attribute in your `ToDoItem` (e.g. `state`) that you can use as `sectionNameKeyPath` for your `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I'll try to explain with a simple example.

Think to a `Food` entity that lists foods. This entity has a `name` and a `category`. e.g.

```
Apple, Fruit
Banana, Fruit
Potato, Vegetable
Salad, Vegetable
```

If you use `category` as a `sectionNameKeyPath` you will find two sections. One will contain foods that belong to `Fruit` category, the other will contain the `Vegetable` one.

The same applies if use a `state` property in your entity (for the sake of simplicity it's a string but you could just use numbers and using a map to map each number to a string value). I guess this it's correct since each item will have a completion state. **In addition, by means of this approach values associated with each `state` can change dynamically**. And this should be part of the model and not of the controller.
Hence, `state` could assume one of these possible values: `@"Overdue"`,  `@"Today"`, `@"Tomorrow"`, `@"Upcoming"`, `@"Someday"`, `@"Completed"`.

As an important note (see Apple doc)

> If the controller generates sections, the first sort descriptor in the
>   array is used to group the objects into sections; its key must either
>   be the same as sectionNameKeyPath or the relative ordering using its
>   key must match that using sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the key to distribute the objects into sections may change every day.

Comment: @mvasco What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the sections should include ToDoItems that have a date (may be an attribute called tdDate), this attribute could be used as filtering key to make the distribution into sections, but then I should find the way to update the key depending on the current date.

Comment: Considering your answer, I have created a new attribute called tdDate, which includes the due date of the ToDoItem. Now I have two questions: 1. How to show the objects on the tableView, 2. How to filter them into the sections (Overdue,Today,Tomorrow,...) I would appreciate to see your answer in real code lines to make me a real approach of the solution.

Comment: @mvasco Could you open a new answer and post the link as a comment? I'll help if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least two reasonable strategies. One is to do a number of separate fetches, one for each category. Each fetch request would be given a predicate that selects those `ToDoItem` objects whose due date and status are appropriate for each category. For example, the fetch request for "Today" would select items where the due date is the current date and the status is incomplete; the request for "Completed" would ignore the date and select all those items whose status is complete.

The other strategy is to fetch all the items at once and categorize them yourself after the fetch. This might be conceptually simpler, and you can still use NSPredicate to categorize the objects. For example, you can use NSSet's [`-objectsPassingTest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/objectsPassingTest%3a) method or NSArray's [`-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a) method.

Spend some time reading up on [using predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) and [fetching objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1).

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of how to substitute the current cellForRowAtIndexPath, which is using a switch loop,with the results of a fetch request?

Comment: Say you have an array filled with all the items that are due tomorrow. Use `indexPath.row` as the index into the array, something like: `ToDoItem* item = tomorrowItems[indexPath.row]; cell.textLabel.text = item.title;` You could apply the same strategy to the sections -- maybe you have an array where each item in the array is and array of items for a particular section. Then you can use `indexPath.section` to get the right array, and then `indexPath.row` to get the item from that array: `ToDoItem* item = (allItems[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row];`

Comment: I have created a new attribute called tdDate, which includes the due date of the ToDoItem. Would you show me the code needed to show the objects on the tableView and also to filter them in order to be included in the right section?

Comment: You show the objects on the table by populating the cells in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just as you're doing. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to write the code for you. How to categorize the items should be pretty clear if you read the documents that I linked above. Try it, and ask for help here if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to group the fetched results by a transient property (e.g. itemState) that calculates the correct section the ToDoItem should appear in (i.e. 0=Overdue, 1=Today, 2=Tomorrow).

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"itemState"
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
```

In your managed object, implement itemState to return the calculated state of the item:

```
- (NSString *)itemState {
    // logic to return @"Overdue", @"Today", etc.. based on whatever logic makes sense in your app
    // see this on how to implement transient properties http://davemeehan.com/technology/objective-c/core-data-transient-properties-on-nsmanagedobject
```

}

Then you can go ahead and use your FRC to implement your UITableViewControllerDataSource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sections].count;
}
```

... etc...

Comment: I guess this does not work since `itemState` will be found in the objects retrieved by the request.

Comment: @flexaddicted not sure what you mean?

Comment: @flexaddicted Oh I think I see what you mean. Since he wants a fixed set of sections, this wouldn't work as is (e.g. there may be no items overdue, so overdue wouldn't show up).