# Fetching and sorting objects into sections

Tags: ios, core-data

In my tableView I have fixed sections and fixed section titles. This is the code for this part of my requirements:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 6;
}


+ (NSString*) titleForHeaderForSection:(int) section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0 : return @"Overdue";
        case 1 : return @"Today";
        case 2 : return @"Tomorrow";
        case 3 : return @"Upcoming";
        case 4 : return @"Someday";
        case 5 : return @"Completed";
        //default : return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section no. %i",section + 1];
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [CollapsableTableViewViewController titleForHeaderForSection:section];
}
```

This part is working fine, but now I want to populate the sections with core data objects.
For this part and prior to fetching the results, I have following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }


    switch (section)
    {
        case 2 : return 3;
        case 3 : return 30;
        default : return 3;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0 : cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell"; break;
        case 1 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Second Cell"; break;
        case 2 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Third Cell"; break;
        case 3 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fourth Cell"; break;
        case 4 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fifth Cell"; break;
        case 5 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Sixth Cell"; break;
        case 6 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Seventh Cell"; break;
        case 7 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Eighth Cell"; break;
        default : cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.row + 1];
    }

    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = ...;

    return cell;
}
```

which is working also fine an populating the sections...but my real requirement is to populate the sections with the objects from a core data entity. That means, I have to substitute the lines:

```
switch (section)
        {
            case 2 : return 3;
            case 3 : return 30;
            default : return 3;
        }
```

with other code lines in order to obtain the real number of rows in the sections.
And following code lines:

```
switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0 : cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell"; break;
            case 1 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Second Cell"; break;
            case 2 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Third Cell"; break;
            case 3 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fourth Cell"; break;
            case 4 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fifth Cell"; break;
            case 5 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Sixth Cell"; break;
            case 6 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Seventh Cell"; break;
            case 7 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Eighth Cell"; break;
            default : cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.row + 1];
        }
```

to be substituted with other code lines to call the real objects attributes.

I have already included in y project all core data stack and also a NSFetchedResultsController.
The core data entity has two attributes: tdText, tdDate. 
The fixed sections are related to the tdDate attribute.

Comment: You seem to be revolving around the same problem again and again :-) - But if you already have a fetched results controller, why don't you *use it* in the data source methods (numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, ...). You already did that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249098/how-to-implement-table-sections-with-core-data, where I (hopefully) showed how to group items into "Today", "Tomorrow", etc.

Comment: (Cont.)  I don't want to sound rude (and I -- and others surely as well -- will help if I can), but perhaps you can try to *use* the answers given to your previous question (such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048835/core-data-objects-in-different-tableview-sections) and describe more clearly where exactly you have problems.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR, you don't sound rude, I know you are willing to help me, but the problem its me. I am only able to follow some tutorials and make minor changes to the tutorial code. In some of the answers you and others gave me I only understand half of them, at my iOS level I need more clear answer and I need to break my problems into smaller parts to fully understand the answers. The other part of my problem is that english is not my mother tongue, and maybe I don't use the right words to explain what I really need.

Comment: @MartinR, I decided to follow Caleb proposal and I have created six separate fetches, one for each category (Overdue, Today, Tomorrow, Someday, Upcoming, Completed). Each of them with a given predicate to select those objects that are appropriate for each category. I have numbered them as frc1,frc2,...Now the question is how to use them to allocate the results on each section in place of the current switch loop in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Look at my answer to your previous question - use an array to hold the section titles and a dictionary to hold an array of results from these queries using the section title as the key.

Comment: Thank you @DuncanGroenewald, I have used your proposal in a brand new project, and it works fine, but using it in my current project, needs to change all the framework. I think there must be an easier solution to implement my needs in my project, which is working except of the population of the section rows. I am trying creating separate fetches, now I only need to be able to distribute the objects on the appropriate section.

Comment: @mvasco I have just added a simpler answer below.

Comment: This is a good guide to get the basics of core data / FRC etc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G36_91H4CKE

Comment: This is a good guide, I am now following it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by putting your hard coded stuff into some better structures so you can easily populate some of the data from Core Data.

Add the following to your viewController's .h file

```
NSArray *sectionsArray;
NSMutableDictionary *sectionMenus;
BOOL                _searched;
BOOL                _loading;
```

In the .m file add the following

```
        #define REMINDER_OVERDUE  @"Overdue"
        #define REMINDER_TODAY    @"Today"
        #define REMINDER_TOMORROW @"Tomorrow"
        #define REMINDER_UPCOMING @"Upcoming"
        #define REMINDER_SOMEDAY  @"Someday"
        #define REMINDER_COMPLETE @"Complete"

        #define SEARCHING @"Searching..."


        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            // This dictionary will be used to store separate Arrays of records for each section using the section title as the key
            sectionMenus = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            // These are the hard coded sections
            sectionsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: REMINDER_OVERDUE, REMINDER_TODAY, REMINDER_TOMORROW, REMINDER_UPCOMING, REMINDER_SOMEDAY, REMINDER_COMPLETE, nil];

            // We start by populating the sections with a single record containing the string "Searching..." so the user
            // will see that the section is busy searching for data to display
            [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: SEARCHING, nil] forKey: REMINDER_OVERDUE];
            [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: SEARCHING, nil] forKey: REMINDER_TODAY];
            [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: SEARCHING, nil] forKey: REMINDER_TOMORROW];
            [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: SEARCHING, nil] forKey: REMINDER_UPCOMING];
            [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: SEARCHING, nil] forKey: REMINDER_SOMEDAY];
            [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: SEARCHING, nil] forKey: REMINDER_COMPLETE];

            _searched = NO;
        }

        - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
        {
            [super viewDidAppear:animated];

            // Each time the view appears we check to see if a search has been done and if not then perform a search
            if (!_searched) {
                _searched=YES;
                [self getMenus];
            }
        }

        // tableView delegate methods to use the array and dictionary as the data sources
        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
            return [sectionsArray count];
        }
        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

            return [[sectionMenus objectForKey:[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section]] count];
        }
        - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] description];
        }
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
            static NSString *inactiveTableIdentifier = @"InactiveTableItem";
            UITableViewCell *cell;

            NSObject *node =[[sectionMenus objectForKey:[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:inactiveTableIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
               cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:inactiveTableIdentifier];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = [node description];

            return cell;
        }

        // This methods performs the queries to get the data for each section
        // and loads each section when its done (ideally should be done in background)
        - (void)getMenus
        {   
            _loading = YES;

            [self makeOverdueMenus];
            UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)self.view;
            [tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


            [self makeTodaysMenus];
            [tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            [self makeTomorrowsMenus];
            [tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            _loading = NO;
            [tableView reloadData];
        }

        - (void)makeOverdueMenus {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate < %@",[NSDate date]];

            [self makeMenu: REMINDER_OVERDUE predicate:predicate];
        }
        - (void)makeTodaysMenus {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate >= %@ and dueDate < %@",[NSDate date], [NSDate date]];

            [self makeMenu: REMINDER_TODAY predicate:predicate];
        }
        - (void) makeTomorrowsMenus {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate >= %@ and dueDate <= %@",[NSDate date], [NSDate date]];

            [self makeMenu: REMINDER_TOMORROW predicate:predicate];
        }

        // Helper function to get the section items and add them to the dictionary 
        - (void)makeMenu:(NSString*)section predicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate  {

                NSMutableArray *reminders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [reminders addObjectsFromArray:[self getDataSimple];
                [sectionMenus setObject:reminders forKey:section];

        }

    // Simple method to fetch data from Core Data store
    - (NSArray*)getDataSimple {

       // replace this line with a core data query
       NSArray * results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First Cell", @"Second Cell", @"Third Cell", nil];

       return results;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will need some time to understand this master piece of code you show me. I will tell you later if I need further help. Thank you again. I guess this is what I needed...and I promise to learn from it not to repeat my questions...

Comment: The hardest part is probably understanding what the Dictionary contains.  It has a KEY which is @"Today" and then it has data associated with this KEY which is an NSArray containing the rows like @{@"First Cell", @"Second Cell", @"Third Cell"}.  So the TableView uses the section title to get the array of data from the dictionary.

Comment: Might be easiest to start by manual creating the dictionary entries

Comment: two dummy questions. There is an error at lines with self.loading, and you put a variable named _todayStartDate, I guess I have to initiate it as follows: NSDate *todayStartDate = [NSDate  date];??

Comment: Just replace self.loading with _loading.  

And you would need to define your own predicates - matching dates is complicated because dates include milliseconds so you will probably never get a match. Start by using todayStartDate >= [NSDate date]; for all of them, you can refine the date searches once you have the tableView displaying some data.  Start by using the getDataSimple method I just added to my answer - replace all calls to getData: with this.

Comment: I am receiving some exceptions, but I will try to solve them by myself. You have been very nice to me. I do appreciate your time, patience and good willing, thank you, your code is very important to me...

Answer (score 1):

In this code example (and in addition to the great advice from MartinR) you are fetching data in the `-tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` method.  That is incredibly expense and absolutely the wrong place to be doing that.  That method gets called hundreds if not thousands of times in the life of your application and you should **never** be performing a fetch there.

Secondarily, you call `-performFetch:` on a `NSFetchedResultsController` **once**.  This is normally doing in `-viewDidLoad` which is ideally called once.  From there you can ask the `NSFetchedResultsController about its current state; you don't call`-performFetch:` again.

As for the rest.  You need to take a step back and fill in the gaps in your knowledge of Objective-C and Core Data before moving forward.  You are being given excellent answers by some of the highest rated people on here and you are not using them fully.  If you continue down this path people will stop helping you.

Fully consume the advice you are given before asking another question that has already been answered.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try to fully consume the advices given before asking another question that has already been answered. I do really appreciate the time and efforts from all people on here. I am here to learn.